# running cloud according to time intervel

Tags: parse-platform

I want to send messages continuously in background for every 3 mins in parse cloud.I searched in internet but I failed to find it .can anyone please send me the code for this.I am new to objective c.I am using parse cloud to send messages and I will send time interval from my app..
This is my code for sending messages.But i want to run that in background when my app runs in background..

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('sendSMS', function(request, response) {
  var toUser = request.params.toUser;
  var fromUser = request.params.fromUser;
  var msgBody = request.params.msgBody;
  // Require and initialize the Twilio module with your credentials
     var client = require('twilio')('xxxx','xxxxxx');     
// Send an SMS message
client.sendSms({
    to: toUser,
    from: fromUser,
    body: msgBody
  }, function(err, responseData) { 
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.error(err);
    } else { 
      console.log(responseData.from); 
      console.log(responseData.body);
      response.success("Message sent!");
    }
  }
);
});
```

Comment: You really need to explain your problem better. Are you asking how to call a cloud function from your Objective C code while your app goes to background ??

Comment: No I can call cloud code function in app but I dont want to use nstimer in app to call cloud function for every 3 min. so same like NS timer are there any function or code I can use it parse cloud. so that Once i will call parse cloud function in my app and then in parse function has to call for every 3 min

Comment: The nearest you can get on Parse are the Background Jobs which can be scheduled with desired frequency on Parse backend.

Comment: Parse.Cloud.job("userMigration", function(request, status) { } this is the code for Background Jobs but how should I assign my timer to schedule that function or run that function for every 3min

Comment: You should be able to schedule a job via Parse web dashboard

Comment: Thank you so much.Can I assign that schedule time from my App?

Comment: I doubt it. You can run a Background Job via REST API but I do not think you can set the frequency of a scheduled job remotely. See: [Background Jobs](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs)

Comment: Ok thank you.I will check with that